# Voicemails found on iPhone that shouldn't be there

Tags: apple-id, iphone, voicemail

Recently, a friend of mine who borrowed my old iPhone 5 informed the that he was able to listen to all my old as well as new voicemails (so they were updated on the iPhone 5 as well).

Before I gave him the phone I did the following:

- Erase all contents
- Log out from my Apple ID
- remove all connections / log out from all accounts on the phone (iMessage, ...)
- Remove the phone from my Apple ID (via iTunes)
- Erase all content & reset the phone

(* during that process, the phone did not have a SIM card inserted.)

Are voicemails connected to my Apple ID? And if not, how could this happen?

(Should I inform my telecommunication provider about this matter?)

Comment: Normal voicemails are stored on the phone carriers servers not on the iPhone.  They're not associated with your Apple ID; you might remember having to setup a retrieval code (that the iPhone keeps) when you first setup your iPhone.  Visual voicemails are stored on the phone, though. Log into your carrier and delete the messages from there until a good answer can be provided.

Comment: Also, when you did a reset did you reset all network settings, too?  There's a separate button for that.

Comment: I'm not sure how that could be. My only thought is to tell your carrier the new IMEI number of your newer phone so they don't think your device is still the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your friend does not have your SIM card or the voicemail password you set up with your carrier.  If those two things are save your voicemail should be as well.